# PlantUML reference to other activity diagram with new syntax

Tags: android-activity, plantuml

I want to implement the activity diagram below with new syntax.

Here is the old syntax:

```
@startuml
partition 1st {
(*) --> "A"
--> "B"
--> "C"
--> "D"
--> "E"
}
partition 2nd {
E --> "G"
--> "H"
}
partition 3rd {
"A" --> "F"
"F" --> "D"
}
@enduml
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure 1st, 2nd, 3rd make sense in swimlanes, but here's something close to what you have:

```
@startuml
|#AntiqueWhite|1st|
start
:A;
fork
:B;
:C;
fork again
|#White|3rd|
:F;
end fork
|1st|
:D;
:E;
|#AntiqueWhite|2nd|
:G;
:H;
stop
@enduml
```

[image]

Comment: No, I dont want to use swimlanes here.

Comment: @fanronghong partitions are swim lanes in the new syntax. What about https://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml/SoWkIImgAStDuLAlKNRCAyaiB4qDpyWiIQqnB2wfuGBBSbavMdC55-Ha0bbErbnMpb2UGc9wOcOUI2D4Xt5HIWsNbPirLsfUYa8nMBqwn1Wh5w0sLsiCEupoG3hSWP8Ura2xyWku781wWQu10000 ?